# AVPlayer does not use prelload

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http-headers, avplayer

I have a problem when I try to play some remoute audio file.

For this I use AvPlayer.
How you know for play something at first we start preload:

- init AVURLAsset
- set observer
- init avplayer

example:

```
 if (trackUrl) {
    self.asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:trackUrl];
    NSArray *assetKeys = @[@"playable", @"hasProtectedContent"];

    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.asset
                           automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:assetKeys];

    NSKeyValueObservingOptions options =
    NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew;

    [self.playerItem addObserver:self
                      forKeyPath:@"status"
                         options:options
                         context:playerItemContext];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(trackDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];

    [self removePeriodicTimeObserver];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
    return;
}
```

So, for audio file which does not have this field at response header "content-disposition:" everything works fine. Preload process is really fast.

example: http://podcast.cbc.ca/mp3/podcasts/asithappens_20160907_50906.mp3

But for audio file which has this field at response header "content-disposition:". Preload process is really long.

example: https://ondemand.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/fa/2017/01/20170124_fa_01.mp3?orgId=427869011&topicId=1033&d=2209&p=13&story=511387528&t=progseg&e=511402985&seg=1&siteplayer=true&dl=1
[image]
It looks like AvPlayer tries to load all file and only after that play this.

***Question:***

**Do you know how I can omit this long preload?**

**How can I miss this field "content-disposition:" at response?**